# Read non-Unicode, non-English text from SQLite database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, unicode, encoding

We have an old MFC c++ application that writes into a SQLite database and another C# application that reads from the database.

The C++ application writes "шаг потока работы" (Cyrillic characters) in the database from a Russian Windows computer.

When the same C++ application reads it on a Western European (Latin) Windows computer, it reads it as "øàã ïîòîêà ðàáîòû" (Latin representation).

When the C# application reads it, it reads it as "��� ������ ����" (Unicode representation).

None of these applications specify encoding type in the database. I want to read the original text in C#.

I couldn't find a proper way to specify the Encoding type when reading the text.

I've tried connection strings such as `Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;UTF8Encoding=True;` but no luck so far.

Also I tried to get the byte array from "��� ������ ����" and convert to Cyrillic but failed.

Does anyone happen know how to read the original Russian text back from a SQLite database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the normal functions in the SQLite C API use UTF-8. The C# SQLite driver automatically converts between UTF-8 and the C# string encoding.

If you do not get correct data from your C# program, then it's likely that the C++ application did not actually UTF-8. This is confirmed by the fact that the C++ application gives different results with different code pages.

If possible, fix the C++ application, or convert the data in the database from the original encoding to UTF-8. As a last resort, you could change your C# application to read all the strings as blobs and then convert them from the original encoding to UTF-8. (In any case, you need to know what the original encoding is.)

Comment: As I said, that would be a last resort. You really should use the correct encoding in the first place.